# WhatsApp storage problem

Tags: 6.0-marshmallow, internal-storage, whatsapp-messenger, storage

My problem is that the WhatsApp stores all the data in the phone memory, which is almost used up.

If I move the WhatsApp folder to sd card, then I'll not be able to access anything from the app.

Is there any way in which I can move the files to sd card but still keep it linked with the app?

Comment: Is your phone rooted? Do you have Xposed?

Comment: @Death Mask Salesman    Phone is not rooted. What is Xposed?